# Can I create non-default EntityReferenceSelection?

Tags: entities, 9

I have the following `EntityReferenceSelection` plugin:

```
/**
 * Provides an entity reference selection for my_entity.
 *
 * @EntityReferenceSelection(
 *   id = "extra:my_entity",
 *   label = "...",
 *   entity_types = {
 *     "my_entity"
 *   },
 *   group = "extra",
 *   weight = 1
 * )
 */
class MyEntityExtraSelection extends DefaultSelection {

  protected function getAllowedIds() {
    return [...];
  }

  protected function buildEntityQuery($match = NULL, $match_operator = 'CONTAINS') {
    $query = parent::buildEntityQuery($match, $match_operator);
    $query->condition('id', $this->getAllowedIds(), 'IN');
    return $query;
  }

  public function validateReferenceableNewEntities(array $entities) {
    $entities = parent::validateReferenceableNewEntities($entities);
    $allowed = $this->getAllowedIds();
    return array_filter($entities, function ($entity) {
      return in_array($entity->id(), $allowed);
    });
  }

}
```

I'd like to call it `extra:my_entity` because I don't want this filtering to occur by default, every time I use it, only when I refer to it using the `'handler' => 'extra'` setting explicitely.

But the core plugin manager gives these errors:

```
Warning: uasort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityReferenceSelection\SelectionPluginManager->getPluginId() (line 65 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityReferenceSelection/SelectionPluginManager.php).
Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityReferenceSelection\SelectionPluginManager->getPluginId() (line 66 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityReferenceSelection/SelectionPluginManager.php).
Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityReferenceSelection\SelectionPluginManager->getPluginId() (line 67 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityReferenceSelection/SelectionPluginManager.php).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

I needed it again, this time already in Drupal 10. The old tricks are no longer necessary, it works without the deriver and the extra key now.

### Earlier

Finally, after some investigation, two required items never documented:

- unlike the core `EntityReferenceSelection` plugins that, for some reason, get away without it, you have to provide

```
deriver = "Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\Derivative\DefaultSelectionDeriver"
```

in the plugin annotation.

- It might be completely unnecessary in your case but you have to make sure your custom entity type has an `entity_key` named `label`. If it doesn't, core will use `PhpSelector` instead of your selector, forcedly.

Comment: It might be that the core plugins you've seen override existing default plugins derived from installed entity types. The question is whether you need a derived plugin at all. Try to not use the `:`  syntax which separates base plugin ID and derivative ID.

Comment: @4k4 From experience that doesn't work - you need the namespace or whatever it'd be called to make the plugin work

Comment: @Clive for `default:*` or a custom plugin ID?

Comment: Pretty sure for custom @4k4 - OP's problem sounds identical to one I vaguely remember having last year and coming to the same conclusion

Comment: @Clive, can't confirm that, for testing I've created a plugin with `drush gen`, which suggests `mymodule_advanced_myentity_selection` as plugin ID, and the plugin seems to work.

Comment: @Clive, generating the plugin via drush works because it follows this weird plugin/group naming scheme described here https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2649712

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link @4k4

Answer (score 4):

As commented, you should not need to provide a deriver for a single entity reference selection plugin. A random plugin ID like `extra_my_entity` should work. The only condition is that you define the (in this case
irrelevant) `group` property with the same value:

```
/**
 * Provides an entity reference selection for my_entity.
 *
 * @EntityReferenceSelection(
 *   id = "extra_my_entity",
 *   label = "...",
 *   entity_types = {
 *     "my_entity"
 *   },
 *   group = "extra_my_entity",
 *   weight = 1
 * )
 */
class MyEntityExtraSelection extends DefaultSelection {
```

See [Entity reference selection plugins break when not following a weird ID pattern](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2649712).

When you extend DefaultSelection then also extend the schema:

*config/schema/mymodule.schema.yml*

```
entity_reference_selection.extra_my_entity
  type: entity_reference_selection.default
  label: '...'
```

---

**Starting a new group**

A group in contrast consists of multiple plugin classes. A base class that derives the installed entity types using for example the base plugin ID `extra`. On installation Drupal will scan the entity types and create for each entity a plugin ID: `extra:[entity_type]`. You can override the base class by using this plugin ID syntax and the group `extra`. These group members then don't need to define a `deriver`, like the core plugins you've seen overriding `default:*`.

It's not a good idea to combine base and group member in one class, because then deriving the plugin ID as base ends up in `a:b:b` and other unpredicted things can happen.

Comment: I can see that it *shouldn't* but it unfortunately *does*. At least right now for me, I tried all your suggestions, and the only one that doesn't lead to the error is what I described. Deriver included. As your link is about 5 years old, something might have happened since...

Comment: I mean, yes, I can name both id and group the same (actually, if I don't, if I use `a:b` for the id and `a` for the group, the core function will assemble `a:b:b` at some point) but 1. Deriver 2. the key named label are both necessary.

Comment: Incidentally, this is how I found out. I started to print out the variables in the plugin manager and suddenly realized that all other plugins have the deriver set but mine. When I added it, it no longer gave the error but it still didn't run my selection code. Then I saw that it still used `PhpSelector`. Then, finally, I saw the source code comment saying that `label` is required. :-)

Comment: You can read in the issue what happened in the last 5 years. They didn't find a solution yet, but they documented the quirks. When using the deriver syntax `a:b` you normally want to override derived plugins. If this is not your intention then don't use this syntax and you shouldn't need to worry about the deriver class. You can solve this naming pattern problem without deriver.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I say. No matter what happened during these 5 years, right now, in front of me, if I remove the deriver, it blows up. If I include it, it works. That's how it is, even if it shouldn't. :-) (Yes, I ended up using the non-colon version. Still. D9.0.7, just for reference.)

Comment: OK, I've added the schema and now my answer contains all details of what is working on my computer as a custom entity reference selection plugin, in contrast to your solution based on core plugins deriving installed entity types. So we have two different working solutions now :-)